# How to search paried devices Kotlin Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth, kotlin-android-extensions

I am attempting to create an Android app to connect to a HC-05 Bluetooth module. I am going through the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices), however, following the documentation I am receiving an error that I can not work around. I do not understand how to the list of bonded devices.

```
fun Bluetooth() {
    val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = BluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
        val deviceName = device.name
        val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address // MAC address
    }
```

I am getting an error at the "= BluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices". I am trying to get the list of devices bonded to the Android phone and pick the HC-05 Bluetooth module to connect to.

I have tried reading through the documentation of the BluetoothAdapter and cannot figure out how to use the getBondedDevices() function. Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: What the HC05 going to do.?  Me I'm answering a few questions here just to pay back the answers that helped me out learning Kotlin over the past month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getBondedDevices()` is not a static function. You need to use the following way to get the `BluetoothAdapter` first:

```kotlin
val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
```

[Deprecated way](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()):

```kotlin
val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
```

And then using `bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices` should work.

But note that you have to also add the following permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure has to be done on a phone with developer options enabled connected to the laptop.

I put a break point on the line if (address==myaddress) and I stepped through the list examining devices with the debugger I used evaluate expression .and once I saw mydevice I copied its address out and *I also copied the UUID out* and made it hard coded in app just to get it working.  [Full code Android project is here](https://github.com/danny117/MYAPP2) and a [You tube of project](https://www.youtube.com/@danny117hd/videos) coming later tonight or tomorrow just got it working a few days ago.  Like and subscribe if you like model trains some arduino mostly old model trains with a touch of underground modern electronics.

```
private fun getMySocket(): BluetoothSocket? {
    val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    if (danny117BTSocket == null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(
                appC, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            val ada = bluetoothManager.adapter
            ada.bondedDevices.forEach {
                if (it.address == myAddress) {
                    danny117BTSocket = it.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```